# Как проставить валюту вместо знака "?" в типе money PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

```
|    cost    |
+------------+-
| 1 000,00 ? |
| 1 500,00 ? |
| 2 000,00 ? |
| 2 500,00 ? |
| 3 000,00 ? |
| 1 000,00 ? |
| 1 500,00 ? |
| 2 000,00 ? |
```

Пробовала заменить на $, RUR, р.
Выдает ошибку.

Comment: Конвертировать в строку и прилепить на хвост требуемое обозначение. Либо выполнить нужное форматирование на клиенте.

Comment: Подозреваю, что это знак рубля `₽`, а консоль его просто не поддерживает...

Comment: В табличке в DBeaver тоже видно со знаком вопроса.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, это чисто числовой тип, без "единиц измерения". Если вы намерены использовать разные валюты, вам придётся завести отдельную колонку.

Comment: Мне так и хотелось, без валюты.
Я сделала insert 1000, а отображается "1000,00 ?"

Comment: @Елена практически уверен, что это всё ещё символ рубля, просто шрифт его не поддерживает...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Форматирование полей с типом `MONEY` в postgresql зависит от локали установленной в переменной `lc_monetary`. Задать оную можно [несколькими способами](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/config-setting.html), например для вывода в валюте США для текущей сессии:

```
SET lc_monetary TO "en_US.UTF-8";
```

Значение должно быть корректной установленной системной локалью. Для *nix систем список можно посмотреть с помощью `locale -a`, а содержимое с помощью `LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8" locale LC_MONETARY -k`.

Для того чтобы вывести число без обозначения валюты для произвольной локали достаточно привести значение к типу `NUMERIC`:

```
SELECT cost::numeric FROM ...
```

Произвольную валюту для каждого запроса задать не получится, но можно формировать строку вручную:

```
SELECT concat('$',cost::numeric) FROM ...
```

Стоит заметить, что кроме собственно знака валюты локаль отвечает также за остальные параметры форматирование числа, как то разбиение на разряды, положение знака валюты и т.д.

Если таковая зависимость вывода от локали не требуется, то стоит используйте более простой тип `NUMERIC` вместо `MONEY`.

Comment: стоит добавить, что если не требуется эта зависимость вывода от локали - то и не надо использовать тип money - используйте более простой numeric.

Comment: быть посему....

Comment: Большое спасибо!